# What type of programs or samples I should learn for Amazon Web Services?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have downloaded Amazon Web Services Java SDK, and signed up for access key. Now my questions are:

- What theoretical  or Amazon Web Services related things should I know? (And from where?)
- What sort of Apps or Programs should I try out since API is at my disposal? (And from where I can get some problems or sample examples?)

Aim is to learn AWS so I can develop my self as commercial programmer for AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon offers a 1 week training in Seattle where they go through most of their APIs and give you code examples and use cases. All (or mosts) examples are in Java and includes real-case application code.

I have been to one of these and the trainer had EXTREMELY extensive knowledge of all the APIs and how to use them. It is really a fast track to understanding what are the numerous services of amazon and how they integrate.

Otherwise, there are a bunch of whitepapers: http://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/

Regards,

Vincent Giguère